# JSON.parse string with quotes

Tags: javascript, json

I have this:

```
JSON.parse('{"130.00000001":{"p_cod":"130.00000001","value":"130.00000001 HDD Upgrade to 2x 250GB HDD 2.5\" SATA2 7200rpm"}}');
```

[JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) says it's perfectly valid json. But on execution I have a `JSON.parse` error.

But, if I change my code to:

```
    JSON.parse('{"130.00000001":{"p_cod":"130.00000001","value":"130.00000001 HDD Upgrade to 2x 250GB HDD 2.5\\" SATA2 7200rpm"}}');
```

(note the double backslash)

It works, but now JSONLint says `invalid json`.

Can someone help to understand this behavior?

Comment: It seems simple to me. Jsonlint is broken ;)

Comment: Where is that input string coming from? is it generated by a JSON encoder?

Comment: @paullb no it's from a PHP $_POST variable.

Comment: @paullb I was not clear, it comes from a JSON.stringify of an JS object

Comment: What happens if you use another library like http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php ?

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.parse` on a string literal instead of just including the JSON text as a normal object literal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a difference between the wire format, and what you have to write in your code to get the wire format. When you declare this in code you need the double-\ in your literal so the string gets a single backslash (otherwise it will interpret \" as an escape sequence for just declaring a " and put that in your string).  If you print out the value of the literal you will see a single backslash.

Comment: Tks Dean, I think I got to first escape the javascript and then the JSON.

So assuming this is coming from PHP how can I "double" escaping it: I've tried this: str_replace('\"','\\"', $json) but it's not working.

Comment: Got it: str_replace('\\"','\\\\"', $json)

Today I learn that there is also a escaping hell :)