# Ruby on Rails JSON.parse unexpected token error

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to parse JSON data in my Rails 3 application with `JSON.parse`. I keep getting this error:

> 737: unexpected token at
>   '{\"0\":{\"class\":\"window\",\"text\":\"Testing\",\"style\":\"position:
>   absolute; top: 8px; left: 8px; width: 560px; height: 290px; z-index:
>   0; \"}

The actual JSON is a lot longer, but it is basically the same.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, we can only answer based on the part of the JSON you showed us, but it has two problems:

1. All the quote characters (`"`) are escaped; they don't need to be unless they are used in a double-qoted string, which it appears they are not.
2. You are missing a closing brace (`}`).

Otherwise it passes based on https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the escaped quotes. This worked: `JSON.parse(content.gsub('\"', '"'))`

Comment: Escaping is hell:  
I had the same problem and this helped me.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066886/json-parse-string-with-quotes

Answer (score 14):

In my case it was a hidden tab character which showed up only when i pasted it into vim.

Comment: The same in my case. Had some whitespace around the object

Comment: Ditto. I had some unescaped `\r` characters in a field value.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use `JSON.Parse()` in-build method:

```
content = "[{\"addon_id\":\"1\",\"addon_price\":\"5\"}]"
# OUTPUT at Console => "[{\"addon_id\":\"1\",\"addon_price\":\"5\"}]"

JSON.parse(content.gsub('\"', '"'))
# OUTPUT at Console => [{"addon_id"=>"1", "addon_price"=>"5"}]
```