# Ruby on Rails JSON.parse "unexpected token" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jsonparser

I am trying to parse JSON data in my Rails 4 application with `JSON.parse`. I keep getting this error:

```
757: unexpected token at '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>BB0CDD4F68DBE9C0</RequestId><HostId>SwLqpcx7wpspbYzXONm1XGRG46dGHxnDroplppsxqtU4v/iVwEGOvpRWpBNR+LMPduTldva/5Nk=</HostId></Error>'
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like response isn't in the json format. Did you look at error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails JSON.parse unexpected token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130822/ruby-on-rails-json-parse-unexpected-token-error)

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Further pro tip: adding this [to your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3164751+please+is%3Aquestion) gives the appearance of begging and pleading, and you may get better responses if you keep your posts short and to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like error response is not returned as JSON. You could do something like:

```
def reviews
  JSON.parse(reviews_json)['Reviews']
rescue JSON::ParserError
  []
end
```