# How to make string campatible for JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jsonexception

In my application when I enter value as **my"name** in text field the framework makes a String like (**this i can not control**):

```
"[{\"id\":\"201500000001002\",\"name\":\"my\"name\",\"colorCode\":\"\",\"version\":\"11\",\"nodeOrder\":\"1\"}]"
```

Now this String is passed to JSON.parse() method which produces an error because of ambiguous name field as

> **\"name\":\"my\"name\"**

```
var str = JSON.parse("[{\"id\":\"201500000001002\",\"name\":\"my\"name\",\"colorCode\":\"\",\"version\":\"11\",\"nodeOrder\":\"1\"}]")
```

This results in JSON exception

Is there anything I can do with the string:

```
"[{\"id\":\"201500000001002\",\"name\":\"my\"name\",\"colorCode\":\"\",\"version\":\"11\",\"nodeOrder\":\"1\"}]"
```

To escape double quote character in `my " name` as `my \" name` to make it valid for JSON.parse method.

I can not control JSON String, I am just passing name as my"name and framework creates a String which is passed to JSON.parse()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.parse string with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066886/json-parse-string-with-quotes)

Comment: I am not controlling the JSON string I am just passing the name and framework constructs it for me which I have to manipulate before doing JSON.parse()

Comment: Garbage in - garbage out. You or your framework do not know how to escape strings. Show the code - how you "enter value" and pass it to this framework.

Comment: I enter value in a JSP which is read and converted into the JSON string without escaping intelligence framework code is not in my control. So i can only play with the result screen "[{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"\"\",\"colorCode\":\"\",\"version\":\"0\",\"nodeOrder\":\"1\"}]"

Comment: @rjoshi What will it output if you enter **`my\"name`**, **`my\name`**?

Comment: @Yeldar then it save name as my"name for my\"name and same exception in 2nd case

Answer (score 0):

I went through a series of `text` replace. You can try this:

```
var str = "[{\"id\":\"201500000001002\",\"name\":\"my\"name\",\"colorCode\":\"\",\"version\":\"11\",\"nodeOrder\":\"1\"}]";

JSON.parse(
str.replace(/\\/i,"").
replace(/{"/g,"{'").
replace(/":"/g,"':'").
replace(/","/g,"','").
replace(/"}/g,"'}").
replace(/'/g,"\@@@").
replace(/"/g,"\\\"").
replace(/@@@/g,"\"")
);
```

It will give back your desired `JSON` array

Comment: following output i am getting [object Object], its not working

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "[{\"id\":\"201500000001002\"}]";
str.replace("\"*","\\\"");
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: `str.replace` won't do anything unless you assign its result back to `str`. Furthermore, this will fail on the OP's example of `\"name\":\"my\"name\"`.